# Turn off the "mic mute" button light on HP Elitebook 840

Tags: hp, media-buttons

I am the owner of a HP EliteBook 840 G1 and the "mic mute" button light on the F8 key is always on.

I have tried to turn it off by enabling the boot options `CONFIG_SND_JACK`, `CONFIG_SND_HDA_INPUT_JACK`, `CONFIG_SND_HDA_CODEC_SIGMATEL` (as mentioned [here](http://www.linlap.com/hp_elitebook_850_g1)), but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

create a local .hwdb file with correct mapping in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-hp-mic-mute-hotkey.hwdb`:

```
# see also: /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnHewlett-Packard*:pn*EliteBook*:pvr*
KEYBOARD_KEY_81=f20                          # Fn+F8 on Elitebook, map to F20
# KEYBOARD_KEY_81=fn_esc                      # org entry
```

then generate a new `/lib/udev/hwdb.bin` file and reload it:

```
sudo udevadm -d hwdb --update; sudo udevadm -d control --reload; sudo udevadm trigger
```

Credit goes to the source [here](https://gist.github.com/HappyCodingRobot/df400e16d0615e98e2c1eee738925d0b).

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you explain this in more detail. How do you "create a local .hwdb file with correct mapping in" and " generate a new /lib/udev/hwdb.bin file and reload it"

Comment: @Vaolter 1. You create a file with your editor of choice (gedit, vim, emacs...) and you write to it the content above.

Comment: 2. You generate a new `hwdb.bin` file by opening a terminal emulator and typing in the given command.

Answer (score 1):

I got the mic mute button to enable/disable the mic, and show the on screen on/off pop up.

Note the light will only go on or off when the pulse audio input control is set to use the built in mic, not any other mic. Then you can enable / disable from the button and have the light turn off.

Instructions are here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HP_EliteBook_840_G1#Enable_the_microphone_muting_key